# Custom font is not working in Firefox.

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, font-face

I have searched for its solution, and I think, I'm doing everything like the suggestions, but it is still not working. Custom font works on Chrome, IE, but not in Firefox. I have used font face generator to generate fonts and the code. I have placed the @font-face code in header, custom.css file (in theme_root/css/) and also in style.css, but it is not working.

Placed this in header.php:

```
<style>

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    src: url('fonts/bebasneue.eot');
    src: url('fonts/bebasneue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.svg#Bebas Neue') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

Placed this in style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    src: url('fonts/bebasneue.eot');
    src: url('fonts/bebasneue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.svg#Bebas Neue') format('svg'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/bebasneue.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Placed this in custom.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    src: url('../fonts/bebasneue.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/bebasneue.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/bebasneue.svg#Bebas Neue') format('svg'),
    url('../fonts/bebasneue.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/bebasneue.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Working everywhere, except Firefox. I'm confused
http://tour.khujbo.com

Also, this font works in html pages in Firefox fine. I have used this font in this template and it works on Firefox: http://khujbo.com. Seems to me, that the problem with Firefox and WordPress combination.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to define this font-face everywhere. You can place the CSS only in `custom.css`. And, you have defined the `"Bebas Neue" font-face` in your `header.php` with wrong URL. CSS is trying to get the font `(woff, ttf, etc)` from  `http://tour.khujbo.com/fonts/`. Please correct your CSS with the right location.

BTW, my suggestion would be, you just place and load the CSS only from `custom.css` and remove all other definitions.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the @font-face from the header solved the problem. The fonts' path in header.php was incorrect. And I think firefox  was preferring header.php rather than custom.css. But the other browsers were importing the font from custom.css. 

Anyway, after removing the code from header.php the font works. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you must always be sure that the font is legal to use on your site.

However Firefox and Chrome should both support TTF.

get more info from [here.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)

Answer (score 0):

be sure u converted font to all format try this site to do http://everythingfonts.com/font-face and the path should be right !

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'GE SS Unique';
src: url('../../fonts/GE_SS_Unique_Light.eot');
src: url('../../fonts/GE_SS_Unique_Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../../fonts/GE_SS_Unique_Light.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../../fonts/GE_SS_Unique_Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../../fonts/GE_SS_Unique_Light.svg#GE_SS_Unique_Light') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
font-family: 'GE SS Unique';
```

}